# List adding in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sum

If I have a list:

```
food_price(banana,2).
food_price(apple,1).
food_price(chocolate,5).
food_price(milk,3).
food_price(coffee,4).
```

And if I want to sum up the price like this using 'total_price/2':

```
?- total_price([banana, apple, milk], Price).
   Price = 6.
```

How can I get it work? I only know adding up number in a list in prolog can be written like this:

```
sum([H|T], Price) :- sum(T, H, Price).
sum([], Acc, Acc).
sum([H|T], Acc, Price) :- NewAcc is H + Acc, sum(T, NewAcc, Price).
```

But how can I match the price with the name of food? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with `maplist/3`:

```
total_price(FoodList, TotalPrice) :-
    maplist(food_price, FoodList, PriceList),
    sumlist(PriceList, TotalPrice).
```

`maplist/3` applies the `food_price` call to each element of `FoodList` and provides the corresponding success arguments in `PriceList`. Then you just add them up with `sumlist/2`.

If you don't want to use `maplist` or `sumlist`, you can create what these do easily with simple list recursion.